# CSS transitions - Changing a property without changing the timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I rotate an image with CSS transitions

```
img {
    transition:all 5s ease-out;
}
```

And trigger it with jQuery

```
$('img').css({'transform':'rotate('+2000+'deg)'});
```

At some point(s) (randomy) during the rotation I want to change direction of the rotation. The image should **continue** the current easing and the current duration. Is this possible?

Comment: Set the rotate to a random value, and at a setInterval...

Comment: The problem when a new value is set is that it starts a new transition. I want it to continue the transition.

Comment: You might want to take the easy path and put 2 different transitions on 2 different elements.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want it to continue the current easing (speed).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 5s ease-out;

}

div.rotateRight {
  transform: rotate(200deg);
}

div.rotateLeft {
  transform: rotate(-200deg);
}

$('div').addClass('rotateRight');

setTimeout(function() {
  $('div').addClass('rotateLeft');
},4000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o3pg8d1d/

Comment: Thanks, but that just create a new transition. I want it to change direction while it maintains the same speed (ease) and continue the current timing.